# Libgdx, Texture region 'grows' when I resize the screen?

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite-sheet

I am loading a texture from a sprite sheet for a game. To get a specific texture I use a texture region:

```
playerTexture = new TextureRegion(Launcher.spriteSheet, 0, 0, 32, 48);
```

The sprite sheet is setup using:

```
spriteSheet = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("spriteSheet.png"));
```

When I use the image upon launching the game everything works as expected:

[image]

However when I maximise the window lines appear between the tiles and at the bottom of the player sprite:

[image]

This is my camera setup:

```
cam = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
cam.position.set(0, 0, 0);
cam.update();
```

And during rendering each loop I do:

```
cam.update();
batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
```

Finally this is the code for when I resize the screen:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    cam.viewportWidth = width;
    cam.viewportHeight = height;
    cam.update();
}
```

The lines are from the next line down in the sprite sheet, (I checked this by changing the colour of the image below each sprite and it affected the lines in game), which leads to me concluding that the the texture region may have grown.

Do you have any suggestions for why this is and any possible solutions?
Thanks!

Comment: You need to put padding around the sprites in your source image to clear up rounding issues like this. Duplicate the pixels all the way around each image 2 times. If you use TexturePacker, this is done automatically for you. Also, if your game needs to be able to resize to arbitrary sizes, the Texture's filter needs to be set to (MipMapLinearNearest, Linear).

Comment: Okay then thanks, will have a go at this.

Comment: Just tried that but still have the same issue

Comment: You said the lines are the same color as the next line down in the sprite sheet, so if you padded your sprites with duplicated pixels, the lines should blend in cleanly. You didn't say how you are drawing all the tiles. You might be introducing some rounding error. But it's more likely you are properly padding the sprites and using a linear texture filter.